# Typographic conventions template / package

Tags: typography

I'm looking for a way (maybe it works out of the box) or package to create a page for conventions used within a paper. Up until now my search yielded only results about typographic conventions in LaTeX and not how to create them...

Here is an example how it could look like (from [here](http://www.plexdata.de/fomsdt/samples/diploma_thesis.pdf#page=5)):

[image]

Not sure if this would be a `itemize` or a `tabular` environment (maybe the latter due to multiline) I started with `tabular` and this is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% surround the \dotfill by a bit of blank space
\newcommand{\spaceddotfill}{\phantom{i}\dotfill\phantom{e}}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3.2cm}p{8.8cm}}
        \textsf{package}\spaceddotfill & Paketbezeichner verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \textsf{Sans Serif}. \\[1em]
        \texttt{file}\spaceddotfill & Datei- und Programmnamen verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Typewriter}. \\[1em]
        \texttt{\textbackslash{}macro}\spaceddotfill & Makros, respektive Kommandos, werden mit einem umgekehrten Schrägstrich (backslash) eingeleitet und verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Typewriter}.\\[1em]
        \texttt{environment}\spaceddotfill & Umgebungen verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Typewriter}. \\[1em]
        \texttt{option}\spaceddotfill & Optionen verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Type\-writer}. \\[1em]
        \textit{defval}\spaceddotfill & Standardwerte verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \textit{Italics}. \\[1em]
        \textit{$\langle meta \rangle$}\spaceddotfill & Metadaten, also Platzhalter für Informationen jeglicher Art, verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \textit{Italics} und sind zusätzlich noch in spitzen Klammern eingeschlossen. \\[1em]
        \ttfamily$\{$\textit{$\langle mustarg \rangle$}$\}$\spaceddotfill & Pflichtparameter werden in geschweiften Klammern einge\-schlossen und verwenden zur Formatierung der Daten die Darstellung \textit{$\langle meta \rangle$}. \\[1em]
        {[\textit{$\langle optarg \rangle$}]}\spaceddotfill & Optionale Parameter werden in eckigen Klammern einge\-schlossen und verwenden zur Formatierung der Daten die Darstellung \textit{$\langle meta \rangle$}. \\[1em]
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Wondering though if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following contains some suggestions on how one could improve your code. I have removed all `\spaceddotfill` commands and added it directly into the column definition. Instead of the repeated `[1em]`, I used `\setlength\extrarowheight{1em}` and to make sure the table fits into the textwidth, I calculated the width of the second column and added `\noindent` right before the start of the table. Lastly, I also used `\lstinline` from the `listings` package for the code fragments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
% surround the \dotfill by a bit of blank space
\newcommand{\spaceddotfill}{\phantom{i}\dotfill\phantom{e}}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\itshape}
\begin{document}
 
    \begingroup
    \setlength\extrarowheight{1em}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{p{3.2cm}<{\spaceddotfill}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-3.2cm}}
        \textsf{package} & Paketbezeichner verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \textsf{Sans Serif}. \\
        \texttt{file} & Datei- und Programmnamen verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Typewriter}. \\
        \texttt{\textbackslash{}macro} & Makros, respektive Kommandos, werden mit einem umgekehrten Schrägstrich (backslash) eingeleitet und verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Typewriter}.\\
        \texttt{environment} & Umgebungen verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Typewriter}. \\
        \texttt{option} & Optionen verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \texttt{Type\-writer}. \\
        \textit{defval} & Standardwerte verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \textit{Italics}. \\
        \lstinline|<meta>| & Metadaten, also Platzhalter für Informationen jeglicher Art, verwenden zur Darstellung die Schriftart \textit{Italics} und sind zusätzlich noch in spitzen Klammern eingeschlossen. \\
        \lstinline|{<mustarg>}| & Pflichtparameter werden in geschweiften Klammern einge\-schlossen und verwenden zur Formatierung der Daten die Darstellung \lstinline|<meta>|. \\
        \lstinline|[<optarg>]| & Optionale Parameter werden in eckigen Klammern einge\-schlossen und verwenden zur Formatierung der Daten die Darstellung \lstinline|<meta>|. \\
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Very elegant using the `\spaceddotfill` in the column definition. Thanks for pointing out  `\setlength\extrarowheight{1em}`, I didn't know about it and it is very usefull for other places, too.