# Alternative for makecell?

Tags: makecell

While working on a solution for [Typographic conventions template / package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569967/typographic-conventions-template-package) I came across https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26692/28139 which makes use of the optional argument for `\\` to increase spacing between rows. This works quite nice.

When trying out if `makecell` might be of help for my solution I found it to break the effect of the  optional argument of `\\`.

The solution is to replace `\\[1em]` by `\vspace{1em} \\` which works but is a bit less convenient. I was wondering though if there might be alternatives for `makecell` which are a bit more "robust" and still easy to use.

MWE (just comment out the `\usepackage{makecell}` to see the difference):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.9\textwidth}}
        \lipsum[1-1][1-3] \\[1em]
        \lipsum[2-2][1-3] \\[1em]
        \lipsum[3-3][1-3] \\[1em]
        \lipsum[4-4][1-3] \\
    \end{tabular}

    ~\\

    \begin{tabular}{p{0.9\textwidth}}
        \lipsum[1-1][1-3] \vspace{1em} \\
        \lipsum[2-2][1-3] \vspace{1em} \\
        \lipsum[3-3][1-3] \vspace{1em} \\
        \lipsum[4-4][1-3] \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `cellspace` package, which enables you to define *minimal* vertical spacing  at the top an bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

Comment: Cou could also use `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package.